# No activity within seconds; please log in again

Tags: phpmyadmin

By mistake I reset all the configuration settings from phpmyadmin, Including the "Login cookie validity" which is typically set to 1440, Now i can't login to phpMyAdmin, How to get retain from these problem?

[image]

Comment: How did you install it via `apt` or manually?

Comment: Via apt, But today i was going to increase the time, but by mistake it set to 0 and i press the apply button.

Comment: ok try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` to reset it...

Comment: @George, Please help me, I am new to Ubuntu and in a big trouble now,  I added the login screen.

Comment: ok try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` to reset it...

Comment: I try this and have some success message in command, Now what to do? Still I can't login into the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55587/discussion-between-george-and-frayne-konok).

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster, Already provided to #George in the discussion, Now i got my answer and describe as an answer.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to add that information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/phpmyadmin-no-activity-within-1440-seconds-please-login/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. First I set `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 2000;` in the `config.inc.php` file and then restarted the mysql service.

But phpmyadmin didn't start. I cleared the older cookies and tried again to login and got success.

Thanks to George for his valuable time.